# How to format web scraping output as table in a CSV?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am pulling some data from a website that theoretically it is a table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'SISWEB-PUBLIC': 'ORA_WWV-RMvAbLGLSxXJOqOTipG30k1M',
    '_ga': 'GA1.3.825042167.1579292801',
    '_pk_id.11.6e3e': '31091343e8e5c6a9.1579292805.14.1605535420.1584973016.',
    '_pk_ref.11.6e3e': '%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1605535420%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%22%5D',
    '_gid': 'GA1.3.532866579.1610911359',
    '_gat_gtag_UA_139253076_4': '1',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2691:2&amp;minimal=full&amp;font=opensans',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
}

data = {
  'p_json': '{"salt":"284140192213841769741724635899547408701","pageItems":{"itemsToSubmit":[{"n":"P2_TIPO_LEILAO","v":"1"},{"n":"P2_TIPO_TITULO","v":"1"},{"n":"P2_PESQUISAR","v":"S","ck":"PCb5bs5LDIDvee0z7u0Uj6YkpPyJBARj2dYQ4WkxnaxN599CNVbrf6gulSAHSU5lQmuIPDpNOaTQUQaUXgpU5Q"},{"n":"P2_DATA_INICIAL","v":"14/01/2021"},{"n":"P2_DATA_FINAL","v":"18/01/2021"}],"protected":"U3PMYyQfm1IU1I_Cn_7v3g","rowVersion":""}}',
  'p_flow_id': '2691',
  'p_flow_step_id': '2',
  'p_instance': '16388465980453',
  'p_page_submission_id': '284140192213841769741724635899547408701',
  'p_request': 'PESQUISAR',
  'p_reload_on_submit': 'A'
}

response = requests.post('https://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/wwv_flow.accept', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

I wanted to know how to get the output (response) in a csv file formatted as table or something that would allow me to treat this output as table. Thank you!

Comment: response.text you could get the content. Then you could use bs4 to select the things from the content.

Comment: Most of what you posted is irrelevant to answering the question. Do you have as small an example as possible of the response text that you would want to convert? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: see it, https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

Having `json` format as shown in your example it's easy to convert it to python dictionary using `json.dump()` method from `json` package.

```
with open(filename) as json_file:
       data = json.load(json_file)
```

Then you can access data as standard python dictionary.

Or having it converted to dictonary by scraping you can directly write it to csv.

Then you can use `csv` module to write the data you are interested in to csv file. In case you have your data in a dictionary it's recomended to use `csv.DictWriter()` API to extend csv table columns with respect to the header.

Example of usage:

import csv

```
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
```

Hope it's the tip you are looking for